# java regex: convert [[x]][[y|z]] to [[x]][[z]]

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string in java.

```
"sdfsdfsdf [[Ubuntu Touch]]: [[Ubuntu (operating system)|Ubuntu]] sdfspp"
```

I want to use `String#replaceAll(regex)` to get the following

```
"sdfsdfsdf [[Ubuntu Touch]]: [[Ubuntu]] sdfspp"
```

I tried

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)(.+)(\\|)(.+)(\\]\\])}", "$4");
```

without success

any help?

thanks.

Comment: Which `Ubuntu` in the second `[[]]` are you wanting? Your title and your example seem backward.

Comment: You should just replace the part you don't need. Check this out http://regex101.com/r/bL0oZ2/1

Comment: thanks Qix. Fixed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (for given string):

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)([^\\[\\]]+)(\\|)([^\\[\\]]+)(\\]\\])", "[[$4]]");
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/tn5hTB)

Comment: Nice avoidance of [catastrophic backtracking!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to keep `z`, not `y`. So search for `\[[^[]+\|` and replace it with `[` (escaping the backslashes appropriately).

I.e., delete the sequence of chars that are not `[`, between `[` and `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex questions should always specify what rules you want your search, or your transformation to follow.  Questions like "I have this specific string, and I want to get that specific string as a result" are never good enough, because we are left guessing what's supposed to happen if you give it a different string as input.  There are always several possible ways we can interpret the question, and we have to guess which one.  We are not mind readers.

Assuming that your rule is "if you see | followed by some text inside [[ and ]], then remove the | and the preceding text":  then this should work:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\[\\[.*\\|(.*?\\]\\])","[[$1");
```

What this does is:

First part: picks up the first `[[`.

Second part: picks up some text, followed by `|`.

Third part: picks up the text following the `|`, followed by other `]]`.  This part is in parentheses; therefore it becomes group 1.  `?` in `.*?` is a "reluctant" qualifier, which means it matches as few characters as possible to get to the next `]]`.  This is necessary because you don't want the match to zoom through all your `]]` if you have more than one `[[..]]` in the input.

The replacement text is [[ followed by this third part (group 1).  Thus, the second part, i.e. the text followed by `|`, is removed.

Your attempt:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\[\\[)(.+)(\\|)(.+)(\\]\\])}", "$4");
```

has a `}` in it that appears to be a typo.  If you remove it, the statement
will pick up the `[[`, following text, `|`, following text, and `]]`, and replace the entire match with the text following the `|` (group 4).  That is, it will delete the `[[`, first part of the inner text, the `|`, and the `]]`, which is kind of the opposite of what you want--you're deleting the things you want to keep, mostly, and keeping the things you want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for something like

```
replaceAll("\\[\\[([^|\\]]*\\|)?([^|\\]]*)]]", "[[$2]]")
```

This regex will search for data which

- starts with `[[` and ends with `]]`
- and in the middle have *optional* non `|` or non `]` characters with pipe after it (like `Ubuntu (operating system)|`) which will be placed in group 1 (not important or used later)
- rest of non `|` or non `]` characters which are placed before closing `]]` like `Ubuntu]]` - this part will be placed in group 2 and we will want to reuse it in replacement

So all you need to do is replace it with `[[` and `]]` with part from group 2 between `[[$2]]`.

Demo:

```
String s = "sdfsdfsdf [[Ubuntu Touch]]: [[Ubuntu (operating system)|Ubuntu]] sdfspp";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[\\[([^|\\]]*\\|)?([^|\\]]*)]]", "[[$2]]"));
```

Output: `sdfsdfsdf [[Ubuntu Touch]]: [[Ubuntu]] sdfspp`

Answer (score 0):

[Try this regex](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html):

```
(.+:\s\[\[)(.+)\|(.+)
```

It works like that:

```
String tem = "sdfsdfsdf [[Ubuntu Touch]]: [[Ubuntu (operating system)|Ubuntu]] sdfspp"; 
tem=tem.replaceAll("(.+:\\s\\[\\[)(.+)\\|(.+)","$1$3"); 
System.out.println(tem);
```

Output:

```
sdfsdfsdf [[Ubuntu Touch]]: [[Ubuntu]] sdfspp
```

**Explanation:**

```
(.+:\s\[\[)
```

This part finds a chain of characters(`.+`) followed by `:`, space (`\s`) and two braces (`\[\[`). Then groups it in first group `$1`.

```
(.+)
```

This part finds all characters inside the brackets `[[` but before the pipe `|` and groups it as `$2`.

```
\|
```

This part finds the pipe `|`.

```
(.+)
```

This part finds all characters after the pipe `|` and groups it as $3.

As return value you want all from `$1` and `$3`.